# "Debounce" GPU fans

Tags: gpu, fan

(I hope this is the right place for a question like this)

So my Gigabyte 2070 super has a low power mode where it turns off its fans and is *super* quiet (pun intended). After a while, it reaches its threshold and turns on the fans, falls under the threshold, turns them off, reaches it again and turns them on... until it is cool enough for the fans to stay turned off. Now, is there a way to debounce this behaviour? I did see a setting for the in the UEFI for the CPU fan. Something like: "take action delay before/after fan yadda yadda".

This would be way less annoying and probably reduce wear on the motors.

Note that I'm not always on windows (most of the time I'm on Linux) so I'm hoping to get a setting that is directly in the GPUs BIOS.

Cheers! :)

Comment: UEFI absolutely will not have any control over your GPU fans.

Comment: I never stated that.